# How to get likes count from facebook graph api which is shared from my web app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am able to get share count and comments count but unable to get the likes count.
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=MY_URL this API gives the response as,

```
{
  "MY_URL": {
     "share": {
        "comment_count": 0,
        "share_count": 13,
     },
     "id": "MY_URL",
  }
}
```

In the same way, I just need to get likes count/ reaction count from API. Please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Assuming a share is an object, there is a way to get likes for object-ids: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/likes

Comment: @jdv that won’t work, this is for “internal” Facebook objects, such as post, comments, etc. External Open Graph objects aren’t covered by this. But the `engagment` field of the `url` node provides more info, as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `engagement` field - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/url

It returns four different counters - comment_count, comment_plugin_count, reaction_count and share_count.

The reaction_count would be the number of all reactions (like, love, sad, …) - that is as much “detail” as you can get in this regard for external Open Graph objects.

Example in Graph API Explorer, for the object `http://example.com/`:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%3Fids%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252F%26fields%3Dengagement&version=v3.2

Comment: what is access token for this. I am not getting the right count using engagement? I think access token is the issue. How to generate it. Sry for this silly question? @04FS. Should i give access for this in my fb app?

Comment: This should work with any token. Please give an actual example URL if you are having problems with this.